# How to Alias .NET functions in F#

Tags: .net, f#

So in F# functions are supposedly first class citizens since it is a functional programming language and can be referenced.

So I can do this just fine

```
    let double x = x * 2

    let times2 = double
```

And now times2 is an alias for double, and has the same function signature
int -> int

Why can't I do this to alias the .NET function?

```
   let write = System.IO.File.WriteAllLines
```

If I try to do this it thinks I am missing a parameter, but in reality I am not trying to invoke the function, I am trying to alias it.

```
The member or object constructor 'WriteAllLines' does not take 1 argument(s). An overload was found taking 2 arguments.
```

Is there a way to alias predefined .NET functions or is it not possible?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Well in fact `System.IO.File.WriteAllLines` is not an F# syntactic  function. It's a static member, so it can be (and indeed it is) overloaded. Then the compiler doesn't know which overload to pick up, he just need an additional hint from you.

You can either supply arguments:

```
let write x y = System.IO.File.WriteAllLines(x, y)
```

or some type annotations:

```
let write  = System.IO.File.WriteAllLines : _ * _ -> _
```

which resolve to a unique overload.

Comment: I see now, it is just awkward because there is a better error message that the compiler could have used.  It could have said a unique overload could not be determined, which it does for other situations, but did not for this one for some reason.